# pytest-mock: Mock an abstract class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm trying to make the following code work:

```
from pytest_mock import mocker

class TestClass(mocker):
  def setup_method(self):
    self.some_mock = SomeAbstractClass()
    self.testsubject = ClassThatIsBeingTested(self.some_mock)

  def test_1(self):
    mocker.patch(self.some_mock, 'some_function', return_value=5)
    assert 5 == self.testsubject.function_that_internally_uses_the_mock()
```

But I get a `TypeError` for trying to instantiate an abstract class.

How can I mock `SomeAbstractClass`?

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Actually that's the best I can think of @ikac

Comment: @J.Doe The definition of `SomeAbstractClass` would help.

Comment: Having tested class require instance of an abstract class sounds like a bad design approach.

Comment: Think about it like mocking an interface in C# @ikac

Comment: I have a general knowledge of interfaces, but not a specific uses in C#. Hows `ClassThatIsBeingTested` being used after all, since abstract class instantiation is issue regardless of whether it is a test or not?

Comment: You pass it an instance of a class that derives `SomeAbstractClass`. I want to mock the abstract class itself because it doesn't have a constructor, only function signatures. @ikac

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of trying to patch a real instance, you can use the [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) module (also provided as the [`mock`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) package for Python 2.7) to create a mock instance:

```py
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    from mock import Mock
else:
    from unittest.mock import Mock

# ...

some_mock = Mock(spec=SomeAbstractClass)
some_mock.some_function.return_value = 5

some_mock.some_function()
# => 5

some_mock.non_existent_function()
# => AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'non_existent_function'
```

This works for creating mock instances of any class—not just abstract ones.

Comment: In the end this is what I did :) With the `mock` package for python3

Answer (score 2):

Using `pytest-mock` or `unittest.mock`you can use the [mocker.patch.multiple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-multiple) method to override the `__abstractmethods__` attribute. By doing that you will be able to create an instance of the abstract class and test the non-abstract methods of it.

Example using pytest and pytest-mock:

```
from pytest_mock import mocker

def test_something(mocker):
    mocker.patch.multiple(ExampleClass, __abstractmethods__=set())
    instance = ExampleClass()
    ...
```

You could also use `unittest.mock.patch.` as a decorator:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch.multiple(ExampleClass, __abstractmethods__=set())
def test_something(self):
    instance = ExampleClass()
    ...
```