# Python: Testing abstract class with concrete implementation details

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, abstract

I have a class containing a mixture of `@abstractmethod`s and normal implementation methods, and I'm wondering how I should go about testing the normal implementations.

Quick Example: I'd like to test the `zoo_str` method, even though it depends on the abstract `description` method. If I have 100 animals, it seems like overkill to write a test in the Lion class, the Antelope class, the Hippo class, etc. What's the best way to do this -- my intuition says I should try to mock `description`, but I can't instatntiate the class and this falls apart if the abstract method is private (`_description`).

```
class Animal:
    @abstractmethod
    def description(self) -> str:
        pass

    def zoo_str(self) -> str:
         return self.description() + "Get more info at zoo.com!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a subclass.

```
class TestAnimal(Animal):
    def description(self):
        return "foo"


assert TestAnimal().zoo_str() == "fooGet more info at zoo.com!"
```

Comment: Now you know that there's no error in `TestAnimal.description`, is that useful? Genuine question.

Comment: Yes, because you didn't touch the inherited `zoo_str` method, which requires and uses the subclass's `description` method.

Comment: ah, right, OP's question is about testing `zoo_str`... thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use multiple inheritance:

```
# test_animals.py
import unittest

from animals import Animal


class TestAnimal(unittest.TestCase, Animal):

    def description(self) -> str:
        return "Unittest"

    def test_zoo_str(self) -> None:
        assert self.zoo_str() == "UnittestGet more info at zoo.com!"
```

Comment: Keep separate things separate. There is no reason for a single class to serve as both as a test case and an animal. You could define the `Animal` subclass as an *attribute* (i.e., inner class) of the test case, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a mock-using variant (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/63777635) showing how to test against all `Animal` subclasses:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("cls", Animal.__subclasses__())
def test_animals(mocker, cls):
    mocker.patch.multiple(cls, __abstractmethods__=set())
    inst = cls()
    assert inst.zoo_str() == f"{inst.description()}Get more info at zoo.com!"
```